# Unable to access URL fragment parent param

Tags: angular

I have the following route config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':org',
        component: OrgComponent,
        resolve: {
            org: OrgResolver,
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'events',
                component: EventsListComponent,
            },
            ...orgAdminRoutes
        ]
    }
];

export const orgAdminRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [
            AdminGuard
        ],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'users',
                component: UsersComponent
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

Where `orgAdminRoutes` is in a different file.

However, when I hit a route such as `http://localhost:4200/google/admin`, though it tries to navigate to the AdminComponent, the CanActivate guard triggers but apparently can't see the parent URL fragment. When I console.log the ActivatedRouteSnapshot, the `url` parameter only has one element ('admin') though `_urlSegment` has 2 as expected (don't know if that's expected behavior), and `param` is empty.

Should I not be able to access the `:org` URL param? I need it to run my guard, but not sure why I can't see it.

I'm running Angular 4.0.x if it matters.

Comment: check [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#pathFromRoot-anchor)

Comment: As in a means of figuring out what's going wrong? Obviously, it's matching the route, because it's getting to the right component, but the `params` member is coming up empty, so my guard isn't working correctly. I can always manually break up the route, but that defeats the purpose of the params functionality.

Comment: when you navigate to `google.com/admin`, only the `path: 'admin',` route is activated, the `path: ':org',` is not activated

Comment: Ok, maybe a bad example, but I wasn't saying `google.com/admin`, I was saying just `google/admin`, indicating google as the organization. Or `org1/admin`. I know it matches the route, as it hits the right component.

Comment: show the full URl you're navigating to

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: okay, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44139451/2545680) then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each activated route contains its own URL segment data. So when you navigate to:

```
/google/admin
```

there will be three segments: `[ {url.path: ''}, {url.path: 'google'}, {url.path: 'admin'} ]`. There is always first root segment for the empty path.

The second segment will contain the `org` parameter in `snapshot.params.org`. Since you need to access it from the child segment, you can do it using `parent` or `pathFromRoot` properties:

```
class AdminComponent {
   constructor(r: ActivatedRoute) {
        console.log(r.parent.snapshot.params.org);
        console.log(r.pathFromRoot[1].snapshot.params.org);
   }
```

You can get the same information in a guard:

```
  canActivate(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.parent.params.org);
```

Comment: Heh, thanks for the answer. Ironicly, I found the same answer about an hour back, but I'm glad someone responded with what I found. It makes me feel better about how I did it :)